# Proving $\lfloor-x\rfloor=-\lfloor x\rfloor-1$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function

Tags: calculus

> How do I prove this floor function property?
>   $$\lfloor-x\rfloor=-\lfloor x\rfloor-1$$

My attempt was to use 
$$m \leq x < m+1$$
and then multiply by $-1$
$$-m \leq -x < -m-1$$

I don't know what to do next, I saw a solution that says
$$-m-1 < -x < -m $$

shouldn't it be
$$-m-1 \leq -x < -m$$

I don't understand: where did the equal sign go? I also don't understand how did one come to this solution. Can someone propose a different attempt of proving this? I also do realize that perhaps this question was asked here before, however that was not very helpful to me to fully understand how to go about this proof. I would really appreciate it if someone helped me...

Comment: If $a<b$ then $-b$ $ \mathbf \gt $ $-a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "multiply by $-1$ step", consider this example case:
$$
2\leq 2.5<3\\
-2\leq -2.5<-3
$$
Is this true?

Also, note that your original relation isn't true when $x$ is an integer. So this must be specifically about non-integer $x$, meaning that $\leq$ and $<$ are functionally equivalent.

Comment: No, because $-3$ cannot be bigger than $-2.5$, so it would be $-2 \geq -2.5 > -3$, I understand this now.. but I don't understand why would someone write it $-2 > -2.5 > -3$ without the equal sign? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @D.Qa See my second paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helped.